# Include config on instantiated ActionView::Base.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

I use this code below in order to render partials from inside a newsletter mailing class. I can't use a standard Mailer in rails, which is why I have to include the render functionality myself.

```
def instantiate_renderer                             
  @av = ActionView::Base.new                         
  @av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths                                                  
  @av.class_eval do                                  
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers     
    include ApplicationHelper                        
  end                                                
end
```

The problem is that it doesn't seem to include my config information from inside `application.rb`, specifically this line:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true }
```

How can I instantiate this but with all my configurations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but maybe `include 'application.rb'`? (I've never actually tried this in the way that you're trying to do it.)